# CASE statement with GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, getdate

Wondering if you can help a little with the syntax here. Trying to set a variable as a month value dependent upon whether it is past the 25th day of the month.

If it is, then it uses the current month (e.g. the variable 'month' will be 10 if the date is 28th October, but will be 9 if it's the 24th October). So far I've got the following:

```
select a
case
    when (SELECT DAY(GETDATE()) >= 25
    then a = (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()))
    else a = (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1)
end
```

I understand you can't use less than or greater than signs, as case statements are only for evaluations (=)? Can anyone suggest another way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need this kind of usage;

```
select
case
    when DAY (GETDATE()) = 25 then  MONTH(GETDATE())
    else  MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select @your_variable = case when DAY(GETDATE()) = 25
                             then MONTH(GETDATE())
                             else MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1
                        end
```

Comment: Few brackets missing here I think

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thanks for your help. I can only mark one as being the 'answer', as Ouscux posted first so he gets it. I'd upvote you if I could though (not enough rep)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `>` and `<` operators with [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). Is the following what you expected?

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) > 24
    THEN MONTH(GETDATE())
    ELSE MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1
END AS [a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF
 DAY(GETDATE()) <=25
 SELECT DATEADD(month,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```